# What's the de-facto way of reading and writing files in Rust 1.x?

Tags: file-io, rust

With Rust being comparatively new, I've seen far too many ways of reading and writing files. Many are extremely messy snippets someone came up with for their blog, and 99% of the examples I've found (even on Stack Overflow) are from unstable builds that no longer work. Now that Rust is stable, what is a simple, readable, non-panicking snippet for reading or writing files?

This is the closest I've gotten to something that works in terms of reading a text file, but it's still not compiling even though I'm fairly certain I've included everything I should have. This is based off of a snippet I found on Google+ of all places, and the only thing I've changed is that the old `BufferedReader` is now just `BufReader`:

```
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::BufReader;
use std::path::Path;

fn main() {
    let path = Path::new("./textfile");
    let mut file = BufReader::new(File::open(&path));
    for line in file.lines() {
        println!("{}", line);
    }
}
```

The compiler complains:

```
error: the trait bound `std::result::Result<std::fs::File, std::io::Error>: std::io::Read` is not satisfied [--explain E0277]
 --> src/main.rs:7:20
  |>
7 |>     let mut file = BufReader::new(File::open(&path));
  |>                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
note: required by `std::io::BufReader::new`

error: no method named `lines` found for type `std::io::BufReader<std::result::Result<std::fs::File, std::io::Error>>` in the current scope
 --> src/main.rs:8:22
  |>
8 |>     for line in file.lines() {
  |>                      ^^^^^
```

To sum it up, what I'm looking for is:

- brevity
- readability
- covers all possible errors
- doesn't panic

Comment: How do you want to read the file? Do you want it line-by-line, as you've shown? Do you want it all in one string? There's more than one way to "read a file".

Comment: Either manner is fine. I left it open intentionally. If it's collected all into one string, splitting it into a Vec<String> would be trivial, and vice versa. At this point in my search for solutions, I'll be happy to just see elegant, up-to-date Rust file I/O code that works.

Comment: Regarding the trait error (`std::io::Read`), note that in Rust you must import the traits you expect to be using *explicitly*; thus here you are missing a `use std::io::Read` (which could be a `use std::io::{Read,BufReader}` to coalesce the two uses together)

Answer (score 431, accepted):

None of the functions I show here panic on their own, but I am using `expect` because I don't know what kind of error handling will fit best into your application. Go read *The Rust Programming Language*'s [chapter on error handling](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch09-00-error-handling.html) to understand how to appropriately handle failure in your own program.

## Rust 1.26 and onwards

If you don't want to care about the underlying details, there are one-line functions for reading and writing.

#### Read a file to a `String`

```
use std::fs;

fn main() {
    let data = fs::read_to_string("/etc/hosts").expect("Unable to read file");
    println!("{}", data);
}
```

#### Read a file as a `Vec<u8>`

```
use std::fs;

fn main() {
    let data = fs::read("/etc/hosts").expect("Unable to read file");
    println!("{}", data.len());
}
```

#### Write a file

```
use std::fs;

fn main() {
    let data = "Some data!";
    fs::write("/tmp/foo", data).expect("Unable to write file");
}
```

## Rust 1.0 and onwards

These forms are slightly more verbose than the one-line functions that allocate a `String` or `Vec` for you, but are more powerful in that you can reuse allocated data or append to an existing object.

### Reading data

Reading a file requires two core pieces: [`File`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/struct.File.html) and [`Read`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Read.html).

#### Read a file to a `String`

```
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::Read;

fn main() {
    let mut data = String::new();
    let mut f = File::open("/etc/hosts").expect("Unable to open file");
    f.read_to_string(&mut data).expect("Unable to read string");
    println!("{}", data);
}
```

#### Read a file as a `Vec<u8>`

```
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::Read;

fn main() {
    let mut data = Vec::new();
    let mut f = File::open("/etc/hosts").expect("Unable to open file");
    f.read_to_end(&mut data).expect("Unable to read data");
    println!("{}", data.len());
}
```

#### Write a file

Writing a file is similar, except we use the [`Write`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Write.html) trait and we always write out bytes. You can convert a `String` / `&str` to bytes with [`as_bytes`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.as_bytes-1):

```
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::Write;

fn main() {
    let data = "Some data!";
    let mut f = File::create("/tmp/foo").expect("Unable to create file");
    f.write_all(data.as_bytes()).expect("Unable to write data");
}
```

### Buffered I/O

> I felt a bit of a push from the community to use `BufReader` and `BufWriter` instead of reading straight from a file

A buffered reader (or writer) uses a buffer to reduce the number of I/O requests. For example, it's much more efficient to access the disk once to read 256 bytes instead of accessing the disk 256 times.

That being said, I don't believe a buffered reader/writer will be useful when reading the entire file. [`read_to_end`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.10.0/src/libstd/io/mod.rs#L345-L374) seems to copy data in somewhat large chunks, so the transfer may already be naturally coalesced into fewer I/O requests.

Here's an example of using it for reading:

```
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::{BufReader, Read};

fn main() {
    let mut data = String::new();
    let f = File::open("/etc/hosts").expect("Unable to open file");
    let mut br = BufReader::new(f);
    br.read_to_string(&mut data).expect("Unable to read string");
    println!("{}", data);
}
```

And for writing:

```
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::{BufWriter, Write};

fn main() {
    let data = "Some data!";
    let f = File::create("/tmp/foo").expect("Unable to create file");
    let mut f = BufWriter::new(f);
    f.write_all(data.as_bytes()).expect("Unable to write data");
}
```

A `BufReader` is more useful when you want to read line-by-line:

```
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::{BufRead, BufReader};

fn main() {
    let f = File::open("/etc/hosts").expect("Unable to open file");
    let f = BufReader::new(f);

    for line in f.lines() {
        let line = line.expect("Unable to read line");
        println!("Line: {}", line);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't really have much to base this off of, but while researching this I felt a bit of a push from the community to use BufReader and BufWriter instead of reading straight from a file to a string. Do you know much about these objects or the pros and cons of using them over the "more classical" version you've shown in your answer?

Comment: @TheDaleks I'm not following your question. `b"foobar"` is a literal to create a reference to an array of bytes (`&[u8; N]`). As such, it's immutable. There's nothing it gives you that you can't do in a simpler manner.

Comment: @Shepmaster Occasionally it is advantageous to have a byte-array instead of an encoded string; for example, if you want to make an app that moves files from one spot to another, you need to have the raw bytes so that you do not corrupt executable files that the app processes.

Comment: @TheDaleks yes, which is why this answer explains how to use a `Vec<u8>` for reading and writing. Those are raw bytes.

Comment: Does bufwriter need to be explicitly flushed at any time?

Comment: @Dragoon that depends on your use case, really. The [docs say](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.BufWriter.html): *It is critical to call `flush` before `BufWriter<W>` is dropped. Though dropping will attempt to flush the contents of the buffer, any errors that happen in the process of dropping will be ignored. Calling `flush` ensures that the buffer is empty and thus dropping will not even attempt file operations.*

Comment: I wanted to add that when you read the file it's going to be relative to where the cargo run command is executed. Therefore, if you have a file called `src/map.json` and you'd run `cargo run` at the root of your crate, you would need to do: `fs::read_to_string("./src/map.json").expect("unable to open file");`

Comment: Is there a canonical way to stream bytes from a reader directly into a writer, perhaps transforming them along the way? Sort of the equivalent of the `|` operator in a shell? I'm base64-encoding a file into an in-memory buffer, and I feel like I shouldn't have to allocate one `Vec<u8>` for the file's contents and then another `String` for the base64 encoding; I should just be able to stream the file's contents into a base64 encoder, which progressively fills the output buffer. But I can't figure out how to do this.

Comment: @BallpointBen [`io::copy`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/fn.copy.html) transfers from a reader to a writer. Any transforms need to be modeled as either a reader adapter or writer adapter.

Comment: @Shepmaster Interestingly I just now ran into a case where not calling flush caused a file to be truncated, 100% repeatable, yet when I explicitly called flush no error was returned.

Answer (score 28):

For anybody who is writing to a file, the accepted answer is good but if you need to append to the file you have to use the OpenOptions struct instead:

```rust
use std::io::Write;
use std::fs::OpenOptions;

fn main() {
    let data = "Some data!\n";
    let mut f = OpenOptions::new()
        .append(true)
        .create(true) // Optionally create the file if it doesn't already exist
        .open("/tmp/foo")
        .expect("Unable to open file");
    f.write_all(data.as_bytes()).expect("Unable to write data");
}
```

Buffered writing still works the same way:

```rust
use std::io::{BufWriter, Write};
use std::fs::OpenOptions;

fn main() {
    let data = "Some data!\n";
    let f = OpenOptions::new()
        .append(true)
        .open("/tmp/foo")
        .expect("Unable to open file");
    let mut f = BufWriter::new(f);
    f.write_all(data.as_bytes()).expect("Unable to write data");
}
```

Comment: I found that I needed to import `std::io::Write` for the upper flow as well.

Answer (score 12):

By using the `Buffered I/O` you can copy the file size is greater than the actual memory.

```
use std::fs::{File, OpenOptions};
use std::io::{BufReader, BufWriter, Write, BufRead};

fn main() {
    let read = File::open(r#"E:\1.xls"#);

    let write = OpenOptions::new().write(true).create(true).open(r#"E:\2.xls"#);

    let mut reader = BufReader::new(read.unwrap());

    let mut writer = BufWriter::new(write.unwrap());

    let mut length = 1;

    while length > 0 {
        let buffer = reader.fill_buf().unwrap();

        writer.write(buffer);

        length = buffer.len();
        reader.consume(length);
    }
}
```