# Reading all file contents in current directory to a vector

Tags: rust

I want to read all the files in the current directory.

Here's my progress:

```rust
use std::fs;

fn main() {
    let files = fs::read_dir(".").unwrap();
    files
        .filter_map(Result::ok)
        .filter(|d| if let Some(e) = d.path().extension() { e == "txt" } else {false})
        .for_each(|f| println!("{:?}", f));
}
```

Here I got a little lost, how can I read all file contents? Should I add them to a growing `Vec` in the `for_each` block? if so then how?

Comment: You want to read the byte contents of every file in `.` into a flat `Vec<u8>`, in arbitrary order (whatever order `read_dir` gives you)? Or do you want it to have some structure like keeping track of which contents go with which filename?

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31192956/whats-the-de-facto-way-of-reading-and-writing-files-in-rust-1-x

Answer (score 1):

If you want a single vec with all files bytes in one you can use

```
let target_ext = OsString::from("txt");
let files = fs::read_dir(".").unwrap();
let file_bytes : Vec<u8> = files
    .filter_map(Result::ok)
    .map(|d| d.path())
    .filter(|path| path.extension() == Some(&target_ext))
    .flat_map(|path| fs::read(path).expect("Failed to read"))
    .collect();
```

if you want a vec that contains each file's content separately, change `flat_map` to a `map` and it will return a `Vec<Vec<u8>>`

```
let file_bytes : Vec<Vec<u8>> = files
    .filter_map(Result::ok)
    .map(|d| d.path())
    .filter(|path| path.extension() == Some(&target_ext))
    .map(|path| fs::read(path).expect("Failed to read"))
    .collect();
```

Comment: `flat_map`ping an iterator of `Vec<u8>` will copy all the file contents at least twice, and makes a lot of churn for the allocator. It might be better to use `for_each` and `read_to_end` each file into a single `Vec<u8>`. Also, a `Vec<Vec<u8>>` doesn't strike me as terribly useful when you don't know what files the `Vec`s correspond to; I would have gone for a `HashMap<PathBuf, Vec<u8>>` or something (but it would be better if the OP can clarify the desired result).